# JQuery format value for date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am updated the value of an HTML input field with data from a query:

```
$("##warranty_end_date#id#").val(warranty_end_date);
```

But the data is store in my database as a SQL Date/Time and has an output like this: **May, 08 2019 00:00:00 -0400**

I would like the data to be formatted like this: **05/08/2016**

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

warranty_end_date = "May, 08 2019 00:00:00 -0400";

var d =  new Date(warranty_end_date);

var f = ("00" + (d.getDate()).toString()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("00" + (d.getMonth()+1).toString()).slice(-2) + "/" + (1900 + d.getYear()).toString();

$("##warranty_end_date#id#").val(f);

Comment: I actually realized that this is outputting dd/mm/yyyy . How can I switch it to mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: just switch the part in the middle with the part in beginning: var f = ("00" + (d.getMonth()+1).toString()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("00" + (d.getDate()).toString()).slice(-2) + "/" + (1900 + d.getYear()).toString();

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could format the date in the SQL query already.
Something like:

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 101)
```

101 = mm/dd/yyyy – 10/02/2008

Comment: Unfortunately I am returning a bunch of columns in my query so I cannot do it that way. Does jquery have a simple mask function?

Comment: I agree this solution would be good to use, but this is not what the OP asked for. I don't understand why this solution is getting up votes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date('2010-10-11T00:00:00+05:30');
alert((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Please consider elaborating a little instead of posting plain code. The objective here is to educate, not spoon-feed.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the following:

```
var date = new Date('May, 08 2019 00:00:00 -0400');
var output = date.toLocaleFormat('%m/%d/%Y');
alert(output);
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y4zemzqg/

Also, look over using moment.js. http://momentjs.com/ Moment.js makes formatting dates and time incredibly easy. I've used it for quite some time with no issue:

```
var theDate = moment('May, 08 2019 00:00:00 -0400').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
alert(theDate);
```

Here is a JS Fiddle using the moment.js solution: https://jsfiddle.net/v923bn5s/